# What java technologies should be used on remote server?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, server-side, backend

I am developing a web game, where users connect to web server, but the game logic is done by game servers. And there are also the db servers of course.

Web server can connect to game server and get needed data then redirect client to it and then client connects to game server to send/get needed data.

Also Game server can get data from DB server.

The questions is that I am using Java EE on Web server and I want to use Java as well on game server. What should I use on Game server as a server-software? Also, using what Java technologies should I implement the game logic and communication between servers?

In comparison with Web server there I can use Servlets, JPA etc. However, such application is ran by Tomcat server using HTTP protocol. I can use the HTTP server on the Game server as well but not sure if it is a right solution for handling connections between web server and between clients.

**EDIT:**
On the game server there is a process which handles the game logic, independently whether a user is connected or not. The game server interacts with database. 
When a user connects, the game server should send/receive information related with the game to the user using constant connection.
Servlets in javaEE allow to handle User <-> Game server connection. 
However, how do I implement the game logic part (i.e., which Java EE technologies must be used), which is ran on the game server independently of the users connected or not.

**EDIT2:**
The game has no animation. However, it is a sports management simulation, that has game simulation and player auctions happen in real time. Game server should handle game simulations and player auctions, which multiple users can be watching and affecting at the same time (player substitutions, strategy changes or auction bids).

Comment: You have not explained your scenario well enough. What kind of game? Quiz game style with regular UI (text, fields, buttons)? Animation? How will you implement the UI on the client side?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be saying that your end user is handled by a [Servlet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Servlet) in a [Container](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Servlet_container) (such as [Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/)/[Jetty](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jetty_%28web_server%29)/etc). If so, in your Servlet you have the full power of Java at your fingertips. The Servlet can open a network connection ([socket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_socket), [WebSocket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Websocket), HTTP, WebServices [SOAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP)/[REST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) call, whatever) to the remote Game server. And the same Servlet can open a [JDBC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jdbc) connection to the Database server.

The Game server could be built in Java, but not necessarily. Most any platform on which it rests (Ruby, .NET, Objective-C, [Xojo](http://www.xojo.com/), whatever) should be able to respond to a network connection such as a socket or WebServices call.